# What does "void-value is not ignored" error mean and how to remove it?

Tags: c++, compilation, void

I try to compile the following code:

```
#include <cppunit/extensions/HelperMacros.h>
#include "tested.h"

class TestTested : public CppUnit::TestFixture
{
        CPPUNIT_TEST_SUITE(TestTested);
        CPPUNIT_TEST(check_value);
        CPPUNIT_TEST_SUITE_END();

        public:
                void check_value();
};

CPPUNIT_TEST_SUITE_REGISTRATION(TestTested);

void TestTested::check_value() {
        tested t(3);
        int expected_val = t.getValue(); // <----- Line 18.
        CPPUNIT_ASSERT_EQUAL(7, expected_val);
}
```

As a result I get:

```
testing.cpp:18:32: Error: void-value is not ignored where it should be
```

**EDDIT**

To make the example complete I post the code of the `tested.h` and `tested.cpp`:

`tested.h`

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class tested {
    private:
        int x;
    public:
        tested(int int_x);
        void getValue();
};
```

`tested.cpp`

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

tested::tested(int x_inp) {
    x = x_inp;
}

int tested::getValue() {
    return x;
}
```

Comment: Where is line-18 and what is the value of CPPUNIT ... \macros?

Comment: Which is line 18? Anyway, the error probably suggest you're assigning somwhere the result of calling a function which returns `void`.

Comment: what is the definition of getValue()?

Comment: @iammilind, I have changed the code to indicate where the line 18 is. I do not know what the value of CPPUNIT is.

Comment: `void getValue();` How do you expect to assign this to an `int`? This declaration doesn't match the actual definition.

Comment: @kaitian, I have extended my question by putting their all the code that is relevant.

Comment: in tested.h, you decleare "void getValue();", you can replace it with "int getValue();"

Comment: Perhaps it is time to pick up a [good book](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list) or two. You are sure to learn faster that way than by simple trial and error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you declare `void getValue();` in the class tested.. change to `int getValue();`.

Answer (score 1):

A void function cannot return a value. 
You are getting a value of int from the API getValue(), hence it should return an int.

Answer (score 1):

Your class definition doesn't match the implementation:

In your header you've declared it in the following way (as an aside, you might want to look into some naming conventions).

```
class tested {
    private:
        int x;
    public:
        tested(int int_x);
        void getValue();
};
```

You've declared `getValue()` as `void`, i.e no return. Doesn't make much sense for a `getter` to return nothing, does it?

However, in the `.cpp` file you've implemented `getValue()` like so:

```
int tested::getValue() {
    return x;
}
```

You need to update the `getValue()` method signature in the header type so that its return type matches the implementation (`int`).